# Cyanogenmod 10 on Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom

Can I flash CM on my Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562? I would like to know if it's possible!

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked on XDA developers for your device or googled around? It seems you can, but be sure it's the EXACT model of device http://thedroidarea.com/samsung-galaxy-s-duos-upgrade-to-cyanogenmod-10-1-jellybean-4-2-1/

Comment: Will it support dual SIM options??? (I am not sure). Moreover, I was asking because I could not find out if it is really supported or not. I had also flashed CM to my two previous mobile phones without encountering issues.... I might do a backup and check if it works!

Comment: I've no way of knowing if it will work, it will have to be the EXACT SAME model, to the letter, otherwise it'll just brick. Glad you mentioned backup! That's the key bit really! Frankly CM builds outside of stable release are very buggy and prone to many issues, by their very nature, and a browse of the tag alone will show you how many problems people are having with it!